# Regex to replace visualforce line only if not commented

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

I am trying to determine if the markup of a visualforce page contains a line of code and only if it is not commented out then replace it. I was hoping to do a simple

`string.replace`

with the regex but not sure it is possible.

The Markup example is:

```
<apex:page >
  <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
  <h1>Congratulations</h1>
  This is your new Page
  <!-- <NS:name/> 
    <NS:name/>
-->

    <NS:name fail="test"/>

  <!-- End Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
</apex:page>
```

and the regex I am using matches the lines that are commented and the line I want but I only want to replace the line that is not commented

`<!--.*-->|<NS.*name.*>`

Here are the results from the above

[image]

I only want to replaced match 3.

I am also not sure if this is enough or if I should simply do more processing and not use regex.

Any ideas on the regex or a better way to go about replacing markup via apex only of the desired markup is not commented out?

Comment: I assume you are trying to do this against locally held files rather than on an org. I suggest the best way to do this would be using XSLT. Visualforce pages are well formed XML so can be processed via XSLT. If this is an option I can add detail in an answer.

Comment: No. Trying to do via appex then will deploy update via api. Was hoping regex would work but thinking it may not be the best choice

Comment: I feel that this may be an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). There are ways to do things dynamically without resorting to using source-code modification, which would actually be restricted in the case of an AppExchange app. What are you *actually* trying to accomplish? What would implementing this solution solve?

Comment: @sfdcfox the problem is customer vf page needs an old component tag commented out and the new component tag added and it needs to be automated so they just need to click a button.

Comment: Use XML processing. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_xml_dom.htm

Comment: Not sure this can be appropriate as sfdcfox said, but if it is XML processing seems the right approach.